# htaccess и конечный слэш

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Делаю 301 редирект, чтобы все ссылки заканчивались конечным слэшем, т.е. при переходе на http://www.example.ru/news был редирект на http://www.example.ru/news/ и т.д. Написал следующее:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.xml$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Все замечательно, все работает с одним "но". У нас появляется левый url вида. http://www.example.ru// Т.е. два слэша на конце. А это зеркало главной, что не есть гуд... Как убить клона? Причем при заходе на http://www.example.ru/articles// все правильно редиректит на http://www.example.ru/articles/ 
Просьба помочь исправить! Не пойму в чем проблема...

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-/]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Не помогает. В этом случае вообще редиректа не происходит нигде.